# Animate adding a subview in a cell with dynamic cell height

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitableview

I would like to animate the `addSubview` of a subview in a cell. The tableview cells have dynamic height, so the animation for collapse and expand is done natively.

This is the code:

```
// MARK: UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyCell {
    selectedCell.showExtraView()
    expandedCells.insert(indexPath)
  }
  if let prevSelectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: prevIndexPath) as? MyCell {
    prevSelectedCell.hideExtraView()
    expandedCells.remove(prevIndexPath)
  }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  if expandedCells.contains(indexPath) {
    return CGFloat(100.0)
  } else {
    return CGFloat(80.0)
  }
}
```

The cell code:

```
// MyCell

func showExtraView() {
  contentView.addSubview(extraView)
  contentView.setNeedsLayout()
}

func hideExtraView() {
  extraView.removeFromSuperview()
  contentView.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The subview (`extraView`) includes the image and the label. The label animates correctly, but the image just appears there as if it's not part of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Animate you view's alpha instead. Turn the alpha from 0.0 to 1.0 inside your animation block.

```
func showExtraView() {

    extraView.alpha = 0.0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6) { 

        contentView.addSubview(extraView)    
        extraView.alpha = 1.0
        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
}

func hideExtraView() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {
        extraView.alpha = 0.0
        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (completed) in
        extraView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```